# Sed command garbled error due to regex

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, sed

I have to following sed command to replace the string '-log -asofdate 20150901' with a string containing today's date:

```
sed 's'/"-log -asofdate [0-9*] "'/'"-log -asofdate $newAsOfDate"'/g'  /export/home/ownclp/temp/runjava.sh.bk > /export/home/ownclp/temp/runjava.sh
```

however i keep getting the Sed command garbles error.
If i remove the `[0-9]*`, the sed command works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `*` goes *after* the character class:

```
[0-9]*
```

The delimiter should not be a slash.

I think the whole cmd should be:

```
sed "s~-log -asofdate [0-9]*~-log -asofdate $newAsOfDate~g" /export/home/ownclp/temp/runjava.sh.bk > /export/home/ownclp/temp/runjava.sh
```

Comment: i tried it, but it didnt work. 
i get the following error : 
sed: command garbled: s/-log -asofdate [0-9]/-log -asofdate 01/08/2015/g

Comment: @ArchitSharma try changing the delimiter for `sed` to something that's not a forward slash eg `s~-log -asofdate [0-9]*~-log -asofdate $newAsOfDate~g`, there's multiple forward slashes when variable gets expanded. @Bohemian you should change your delimiter in answer too

Comment: use maybe a `\{8\}` instead of `*` to insure taking the correct reference with a date